# How can I switch the name in the row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's my query:

```
select project_number, concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as employee_name, department_name 
from ex.projects p right join employees e 
On e.employee_id = p.employee_id
right join departments d 
on d.department_number = e.department_number

order by department_name
```

[image: Here's my output]

[image: Wanted Output]

How can I switch the two people names? Need "cindy smith' to be on bottom of "Ralph simonian" and "Robert Aaronsen" to be on top "Ralph simonian"

Comment: Any particular reference between people, if is because of the status of the job and you got a column about that just JOIN the table and group by this column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this using `left join` rather than `right join`.  Reading `left join` is easier:  keep everything in the *first* table and then matching rows in the rest.  This is easier to read than . . . "wait til you see what is in the last table to see what the rows are going to be."

But leaving your method, you need an `order by`:

```
select project_number, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as employee_name,
       department_name 
from ex.projects p right join
     employees e 
     On e.employee_id = p.employee_id right join
     departments d 
     on d.department_number = e.department_number
order by department_name, last_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample, you only need to add in the order clause the project number and employee name in descending order

```
order by department_name, project_number, employee_name desc
```

Comment: I do not think DESC will give the desired output.

Comment: i looked at the resulting data and forgot to check his query. this may do after his original query.